# Merge list of lists in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this 2 lists of list:

```
list1= [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 0, 3579], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 60]]

list2= [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740],['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user4', 288, 'Feb 2017', 60, 10]]
```

And I desire to output this:

```
desiredlist =[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 550, 740], ['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0], ['user4', 288, 'Feb 2017', 60, 10]]
```

For that I have this function:

```
def mergesafirmacheta(list1,list2):
    desiredlist = []
    for id, n1, dates, n2, n3 in list1:
        counter = 0
        for list_2 in list2:
            if n1 == list_2[1]:
                desiredlist.append(list_2[:3] + [n2, list_2[4]])
            else:
                   counter += 1
                   if counter == len(list2):
                       desiredlist.append([id, n1, dates, n2, 0])
    print (desiredlist)
```

But this will output just this:

```
desiredlist =[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 550, 740], ['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0]]
```

^^ user4 is missing (check my desired output), I can see why from my function, I try to add this after my first is statement:

```
elif list_2[1] != n1:
    desiredlist.append(list_2)
```

But this won't work, this are the rules to compute the desired list:

When `list2[1] == list1[1]` (example 186 == 186) append to my `desiredlist` `list2[0], list2[1], list2[2], list1[3], list2[4]`, if you have a `list1[1]` that is not in `list2` lists change append to `desiredlist list1[0], list1[1], list1[2], list1[3], 0,` and if a `list2[1]` that is not in `list1` lists append to `desiredlist list2[0], list2[1], list2[2], list2[3], list2[4]`. This is a bit hard to fallow but I think is much easier to check for my desired output and what I actually output right now.

Comment: So all the "values" should originate from the second list? It is not really clear to me how you merge the input.

Comment: Why won't you use a dictionary instead?

Comment: From both, in my desired output there is user3 (original from list1) and user4(original from list2)

Comment: It’s very unclear to me when a value will be carried over from one list or another. For example, for user 1, the `550` is taken from the first and the `740` is taken from the second list. But for user 2, the `1000` of the second list wins over the `3579` from the first. Why?! What is the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do what you intended by changing your format. I convert all your sublists into `dict` with the key `user`.

Because it easier to merge dict and the order of `user` in your sublists doesn't matter.

The last steps is to iterate over the merged `dict` of `list1` and `list2` and do your special operation. As I understood, is to take the before last number of `list1` and merge it with `list2`. Then you recreate your desired sublist.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 0, 3579], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 60]]
list2 = [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740],['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user4', 288, 'Feb 2017', 60, 10]]

# Transform list to dict with key as 'userN'
def to_dict(lst): return {x[0]: x[1:] for x in lst} 

# Now create a dict that combined list of user1..N+1
tmp_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in chain(to_dict(list1).items(), to_dict(list2).items()):
  tmp_dict[k].append(v)

desired_output = []
for k, v in tmp_dict.items():
  if len(v) == 2:
    v[1][-2] = v[0][-2] # Take the before last of list1 to remplace with before last one of list2
    desired_output.append([k] + v[1])
  else:
    desired_output.append([k] + v[0])

print(desired_output)
```

Output:

```
[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 550, 740], ['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 60], ['user4', 288, 'Feb 2017', 60, 10]]
```

**EDIT**

It seems I make a mistake and your `list1` have to check all the content of `list2`, in that case you should make a `dict` of `list2` first and apply your specific condition after. eg:

```
from itertools import chain

list1 = [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 0, 3579], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 60]]
list2 = [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740],['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user4', 288, 'Feb 2017', 60, 10]]

# Transform list to dict with key as 'userN'
def to_dict(lst): return {x[0]: x[1:] for x in lst} 

# First, transfrom list2 to dict
list2_dict = {}
for k, v in to_dict(list2).items():
  list2_dict[k] = v

# Then iterate on list1 to compare
desired_output = []
for k, v in to_dict(list1).items():
  if k in list2_dict: # key of list1 exists in list2
    list2_dict[k][-2] = v[-2] # replace value
    desired_output.append([k] + list2_dict[k]) # Then add list2
    list2_dict.pop(k) # And remove it from old dict
  else: # list1 does not exists in list2
    v[-1] = 0 # Set last element to zero
    desired_output.append([k] + v)

for k, v in list2_dict.items(): # Now add elements present only in list2
  desired_output.append([k] + v)

print(desired_output)
```

output:

```
[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 550, 740], ['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0], ['user4', 288, 'Feb 2017', 60, 10]]
```

**Note**: we can get rid of `defaultdict` since the same key is not being to be added twice.

Comment: Same thing here ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 60] should be: ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0], like I posted in my desired output. ( if you have a list1[1] that is not in list2 lists append to desiredlist list1[0], list1[1], list1[2], list1[3], 0)

Comment: @TatuBogdan, Oh wow, this is a tricky condition. Well in that case you option will be to first transform you second list in a `dict` and THEN try with the second one, you can add special check there after that.

Comment: @TatuBogdan please check my edit, I tried to include your remark in your "tricky" condition

Comment: Works, thank you, I will study the code and try to understand it more into detail. Nice one, you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
list1= [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Apr 2017', 550, 555], ['user2', 282, 'Mai 2017', 0, 3579], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 60]]

list2= [['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 0, 740],['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user4', 288, 'Feb 2017', 60, 10]]

final_list = []
for l1_data, l2_data in zip(list1, list2):
    if l1_data[0] == l2_data[0]:
        for index, elem in enumerate(l2_data):
            if index+1 <= len(l1_data):
                if not elem and l1_data[index]:
                    l2_data[index] = l1_data[index]                    
    else: final_list.append(l1_data)
    final_list.append(l2_data)
print final_list
```

Ouptut:

```
[['user1', 186, 'Feb 2017, Mar 2017, Mai 2017', 550, 740], ['user2', 282, 'Feb 2017', 0, 1000], ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 60], ['user4', 288, 'Feb 2017', 60, 10]]
```

Comment: I was checking your output, only problem is in this list: ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 60] when you don't have a match I would like with 0 like this: ['user3', 281, 'Mai 2017', 10, 0] (I posted in my desired output.

Comment: if you have a list1[1] that is not in list2 lists append to desiredlist list1[0], list1[1], list1[2], list1[3], 0

Comment: But there is no any list containing user3 in list2. Thats why I added those as it is in the final list.

Comment: I see, it's on list1, it isn't possible when you loop to also check if it's in list1 and not in list2 and then make that index[4] to 0?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the distinct second element of both list combined:

```
for n in set([item[1] for item in list1+list2]):
```

then you can decide to add to your desired list by looking up n in both list